# what is the equivalent of datastage convert function in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw, datastage

Convert function return a copy of variable with every occurrence of specified characters in variable replaced with other specified characters. Every time a character to be converted appears in variable, it is replaced by the replacement character.
example:

```
A="NOW IS THE TIME"
PRINT A
A=CONVERT('TI','XY',A)
PRINT A
A=CONVERT('XY','T',A)
PRINT A
```

OUTPUT

```
NOW IS THE TIME
NOW YS XHE XYME
NOW S THE TME
```

How to achieve this in db2 query.

Answer (score 1):

I think the equivalent is [`translate()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_translate.html):

```
translate(A, 'XY', 'TI')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d71831754c6d0d85b471bc46bfbd471e) is a db<>fiddle.

This is not *exactly* equivalent.  Unfortunately, `translate()` in DB2 does not remove characters (`translate()` in Oracle does) by default.  Instead, DB2 replaces them with spaces or an explicit pad character when the "to" string is shorter than the "from" string.  It only removes characters when the `pad` has a length of zero.

```
select translate(translate('NOW IS THE TIME', 'XY', 'TI'), 'T', 'XY', '')
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Why not use TRANSLATE with an empty padding, works for LUW DB2 9.7: translate('NOW IS THE TIME', '', 'I', '') == 'NOW S THE TME'; see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000862.html , there: "The value must have a length attribute of zero or one. If a zero-length string is specified, characters in the from-string-exp with no corresponding character in the to-string-exp are removed from char-string-exp or graphic-string-exp."

Answer (score 1):

TRANSLATE is a fully functional equivalent in DB2 LUW (e.g. 9.7):
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000862.html

```
SET A = 'NOW IS THE TIME';
--PRINT A
SET A = TRANSLATE(A, 'XY', 'TI');
--PRINT A
SET A = TRANSLATE(A, 'T', 'XY', ''); --empty padding crucial!
--PRINT A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_replace.html):

```
REPLACE(A, 'TI', 'XY')
```

Answer (score 0):

The REPLACE function in DB2 replaces all occurrences of search-string in source-string with replace-string. If search-string is not found in source-string, source-string is returned unchanged.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_replace.html
Usefully, DataStage also has a Replace() function, with the same functionality.